# How much space is left on my hard drive?

Tags: macos, disk-space

Where do I have to go to find out how much space I have left on my hard drive?

As you can imagine from the question I am new to Apple and don't know where to look.

I used a program called "Cleanup" on my old Windows machine which did what the name says, great little program, is there anything similar for Apple, something which cleans up files like cache and cookies?

Comment: You may want to ask about CleanUp alternatives in another question. This will attract more focused answers.

Comment: @Graham Miln thanks for the edit......now all I need is the answer:-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

 Menu > About this Mac

[image]

Then the Storage tab

[image]

For cleanup, [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/mac/ccleaner) exists for Mac; there's also [CleanMyDrive](http://macpaw.com/cleanmydrive) & a whole raft of others. I wouldn't particularly recommend any of them, as they've all been known to throw out the wrong bit, just like on Windows.

Comment: I've been using CCleaner for over a year and haven't had any issues

Comment: @ColeJohnson I'm still trying to refill my browser icon cache after one of those cleaners wiped them all for me

Comment: @Tetsujin CCleaner lets you choose what you want to wipe. Just tell it not to wipe your icon cache.